# Prove that there isn't a nonconstant monic polynomial $p(z)$ of degree $n$ so that $|p(z)| < R^n$ on $|z| = R$, where $R > 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, contest-math

> Prove that there does not exist a nonconstant polynomial $p(z)$ in the complex variable $z$ so that $|p(z)| < R^n$ on $|z| = R$, where $R > 0$ and $p(z)$ is monic and of degree $n$.

I know that a nonconstant polynomial of degree less than $n$ must have at most $n-1$ zeroes. So it might be useful to derive a contradiction by assuming that such a polynomial $p(z) = z^n + a_{n-1} z^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0$ exists. Then $|p(z)| < |-z^n|$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}, |z| = R$.

> I was wondering if there's a "simple" way to solve this problem that doesn't use complex theorems like Rouche's theorem?

Comment: compute $\int_{|z|=R}|p(Re^{i\theta}|^2d\theta$ and notice that it is $2\pi R^{2n}+$ nonnegative terms etc

Comment: @Conrad could you provide more details? How would that lead to a contradiction? Also, is the integral you're suggesting to compute equal to $\int_0^{2\pi} |p(R e^{i\theta})|^2 d\theta$?

Comment: Apply the Parseval identity. If $|p(Re^{i\theta})|<R^n$ the integral is strictly less than $2\pi R^{2n}$ which leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\int_{|z|=R}\frac 1{z^k}~dz=0$ if $k\geq 2,$ one has $$\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{p(z)}{z^{n+1}}~dz=1,$$ using the monic condition on $p(z)$.

If $|p(z)|<R^n$ on $|z|=R$, then $$\left|\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{p(z)}{z^{n+1}}~dz\right|<\frac 1{2\pi}\cdot \frac{R^n}{R^{n+1}}\cdot 2\pi R=1,$$ a contradiction.